# keyError using while loop dictionary iteration

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop

I am trying to iterate couple of inputs and then populating the dictionary but i am keep getting this keyError everytime at last key when i input last key it throws me this error.

```
 # Get user input and define our roster
roaster = {}
while True:
    position = input('position: ')
    player = input('player: ')
    roaster[position] = [player]
    roaster.update()
    if len(roaster) == 1:
        break
print(f'Your starting {len(roaster)} for the upcoming basketball season')

print(f'\t\t{roaster[player]}:\t\t{roaster[position]}')
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/Basketball_Roaster_App/basketball_ball_roaster.py", line 16, in <module>
print(f'\t\t{roaster[player]}:\t\t{roaster[position]}')
KeyError: 'mike'
```

Comment: What input are you supplying to get this error?

Comment: by the way, roster is spelled without an 'a'

Comment: What is that `update` function? Also, why is there always only one player allowed -- the `break` ensures that. Is it meant to be a very small roaster?

Comment: i am supplying string

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `roaster[player]`

Your las input as player is mike, so the dict is
`roaster = {position: 'mike'}`

You can only access the dict with keys, so you need to use the posistion to access.
Python is trying to find 'mike' in the keys and can't find it.

What you should do is:

```
for key in roaster:
    print(roaster[key]: key)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

> roaster={position : player}
>
> print roaster.items()

Answer (score 0):

Your `roaster` uses *positions* as keys, not *players*.